# lapply alternative to for loop to append to data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame:

```
df<-structure(list(chrom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                       2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
                     pos = c(10L, 200L, 134L, 400L, 600L, 1000L, 20L, 33L, 40L, 
                             45L, 50L, 55L, 100L, 123L)), .Names = c("chrom", "pos"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
> head(df)
  chrom  pos
1     1   10
2     1  200
3     1  134
4     1  400
5     1  600
6     1 1000
```

And I want to calculate `pos[i+1]` - `pos[i]` on the sample chromosome (`chrom`)

By using a for loop over each `chrom` level, and another over each row I get the expected results:

```
 for (c in levels(df$chrom)){
    df_chrom<-filter(df, chrom == c)
    df_chrom<-arrange(df_chrom, df_chrom$pos)

    for (i in 1:nrow(df_chrom)){
      dist<-(df_chrom$pos[i+1] - df_chrom$pos[i])
      logdist<-log10(dist)
      cat(c, i, df_chrom$pos[i], dist, logdist, "\n")
    }
  }
```

However, I want to save this to a data frame, and think that `lapply` or `apply` is the right way to go about this. I can't work out how to make the `pos[i+1]` - `pos[i]` calculation though (seeing as `lapply` works on each row/column.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Here's the output from my solution:

```
chrom index pos dist log10dist
1 1 10 124 2.093422 
1 2 134 66 1.819544 
1 3 200 200 2.30103 
1 4 400 200 2.30103 
1 5 600 400 2.60206 
1 6 1000 NA NA 
2 1 20 13 1.113943 
2 2 33 NA NA 
3 1 40 5 0.69897 
3 2 45 NA NA 
4 1 50 5 0.69897 
4 2 55 45 1.653213 
4 3 100 23 1.361728 
4 4 123 NA NA
```

Comment: You can initiate a `list` and save the output of the `for` loop to each list elements.

Answer (score 1):

We could do this using a group by difference.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'chrom', `order` the 'pos', get the difference of 'pos' (`diff`) and also `log` of the difference

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(pos), {v1 <- diff(pos)
                   .(index = seq_len(.N), pos = pos, 
                      dist = c(v1, NA), logdiff = c(log10(v1), NA))}

               , by = chrom]
#    chrom index  pos dist  logdiff
# 1:     1     1   10  124 2.093422
# 2:     1     2  134   66 1.819544
# 3:     1     3  200  200 2.301030
# 4:     1     4  400  200 2.301030
# 5:     1     5  600  400 2.602060
# 6:     1     6 1000   NA       NA
# 7:     2     1   20   13 1.113943
# 8:     2     2   33   NA       NA
# 9:     3     1   40    5 0.698970
#10:     3     2   45   NA       NA
#11:     4     1   50    5 0.698970
#12:     4     2   55   45 1.653213
#13:     4     3  100   23 1.361728
#14:     4     4  123   NA       NA
```

---

Upon running the OP's code the output printed are

```
#1 1 10 124 2.093422 
#1 2 134 66 1.819544 
#1 3 200 200 2.30103 
#1 4 400 200 2.30103 
#1 5 600 400 2.60206 
#1 6 1000 NA NA 
#2 1 20 13 1.113943 
#2 2 33 NA NA 
#3 1 40 5 0.69897 
#3 2 45 NA NA 
#4 1 50 5 0.69897 
#4 2 55 45 1.653213 
#4 3 100 23 1.361728 
#4 4 123 NA NA
```

Comment: Alternately, `.(pos = pos[-.N], dist = v1 <- diff(pos), logdiff = log10(v1))`, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

We split `df` by `df$chrom` (Note that we reorder both `df` and `df$chrom` before splitting). Then we go through each of the subgroups (the subgroups are called `a` in this example) using `lapply`. On the `pos` column of each subgroup, we calculate difference (`diff`) of consecutive elements and take `log10`. Since `diff` decreases the number of elements by 1, we add a `NA` to the end. Finally, we `rbind` all the subgroups together using `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df[order(df$chrom, df$pos),], df$chrom[order(df$chrom, df$pos)]),
                      function(a) data.frame(a, dist = c(log10(diff(a$pos)), NA))))
#     chrom  pos     dist
#1.1      1   10 2.093422
#1.3      1  134 1.819544
#1.2      1  200 2.301030
#1.4      1  400 2.301030
#1.5      1  600 2.602060
#1.6      1 1000       NA
#2.7      2   20 1.113943
#2.8      2   33       NA
#3.9      3   40 0.698970
#3.10     3   45       NA
#4.11     4   50 0.698970
#4.12     4   55 1.653213
#4.13     4  100 1.361728
#4.14     4  123       NA
```

Comment: Thanks but the output is different from what I get. The `logdist` for the first row in my data frame should be `log10(134-10) == 2.093422`, your output puts this on row 2

Comment: For a newcomer to R this is easier to understand than the other answer - would you be able to break down what's going on here?

Comment: @fugu, I have added some description